# Change Ubuntu splash screen

Tags: boot, plymouth

Hoping someone can help me out with what I thought would be a simple fix but has proved anything but.

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS server with the default boot target of multi-user.target - so no GUI desktop. I would like to display a simple jpg or png file on the screen at boot time and nothing else.

I started by editing /etc/default/grub and adding GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash" which got rid of all the verbose logging to screen at boot / shutdown time.

And I now just get the Ubuntu coloured background and the text Ubuntu 20.04 on screen as well as four dots that go from white to red as it progresses.

But I couldn't figure out how to change this in anyway.

So I installed a different plymouth these via apt install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo and now see a different theme at boot time. So progress of sorts.

It also created this folder /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-gnome-logo with a number of other files, png files and a large .script file. And this is where it's got confusing and I'm a bit stuck.

Does anyone know of a simple way to just display a single image at boot / shut down time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you basically want to make your own simple plymouth theme. Your best bet would be to modify an existing theme and switch the images/text.

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Plymouth/Theme_creation

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for such a late update to this, but I did solve it in the end. Massively frustrating at the time over something I thought would be incredibly simple to change. So.

In my grub.timeout file I have this:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"
```

I created a mytheme.plymouth file with this in it:

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=mytheme
Description=Fancy Description Here
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mytheme
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mytheme/mytheme.script
```

I created a mytheme.script file with this in it:

```
wallpaper_image = Image("myfancyimage.png");
screen_width = Window.GetWidth();
screen_height = Window.GetHeight();
resized_wallpaper_image = wallpaper_image.Scale(screen_width,screen_height);
wallpaper_sprite = Sprite(resized_wallpaper_image);
wallpaper_sprite.SetZ(-100);

#Sets the background white. 
# Alternatively you can do a gradient by setting different colors
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Created a tar file that included the script, plymouth + png files in a dir called mytheme - or whatever you want.

The tar file was extracted to /usr/share/plymouth/themes/

I then ran these two commands:

```
update-alternatives --install \
 /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth \
 /usr/share/plymouth/themes/mytheme/mytheme.plymouth 100

update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot and my theme was displayed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Much easier way. It's a total cheat but really all you have to do is replace the existing background image with your new one using the original filename, since grub will be configured to use that file name.

As root go to /usr/share/backgrounds/ (mine is ubuntu-mate-jammy)
You should see the splash screen logo you are now using as a .png filetype.
Select the photo you want. Edit it using gimp to be the same size as the current splash screen photo ( will vary depending on your screen).
Copy the filename for the current splash screen, then rename the current splash screen "Old " just so you don't lose it.
Paste your new .png image into the folder and rename it to to match the filename of the original.

Worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replacing the 'grub.timeout file' wording by the real file location :
`/etc/default/grub` file ... would be helping people looking for a quick fix.